# Google Sheets / Excel - Create a minimum list based on multiple cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I'm trying to get a minimum number (C) if A B and D combined match with any other row

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | iOS | Safari | 14.0 | mobile |
| 2 | Android | Samsung Internet | 13.2 | mobile |
| 4 | Macintosh | Safari | 14.0 | desktop |
| 5 | Android | Chrome | 88.0 | mobile |
| 6 | Android | Chrome | 87.0 | mobile |
| 7 | Android | Samsung Internet | 13.0 | mobile |
| 8 | iOS | Safari | 12.1 | mobile |
| 9 | Windows | Chrome | 87.0 | desktop |
| 10 | iOS | Safari | 12.1 | tablet |
| 11 | Linux | Chrome | 79.0 | desktop |
| 12 | Windows | Chrome | 89.0 | desktop |
| 13 | Windows | Chrome | 88.0 | desktop |
| 14 | iOS | Safari | 13.1 | mobile |
| 15 | Android | Android Webview | 88.0 | mobile |
| 16 | Android | Chrome | 89.0 | mobile |

I've tried a few things but my knowledge is limited and I'm out of my depth here

many thanks in advance
I'd like this to end up something like this but in another area (so not overwriting the data)

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Macintosh | Safari | 14.0 | desktop |
| 3 | Android | Chrome | 87.0 | mobile |
| 4 | Android | Samsung Internet | 13.0 | mobile |
| 5 | iOS | Safari | 12.1 | mobile |
| 6 | Windows | Chrome | 87.0 | desktop |
| 7 | iOS | Safari | 12.1 | tablet |
| 8 | Linux | Chrome | 79.0 | desktop |
| 9 | Android | Android Webview | 88.0 | mobile |

Comment: In Excel, use Power Query.  Group by columns A, B & D; and for operation set to the Minimum of Column C.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**: Using a pivot table. Set A, B and D in the Rows section, and then C into your Values section. Then summarize values by MIN. Of course, this will place C at the end.

**Method 2**: If you really need Column C before column D, then another way is by using MINIFS formula. First, copy A, B and D then paste into another area. Remove Duplicates and add a column between B and D for your formula.

Cell O3 formula:

```
=MINIFS(C:C,A:A,M3,B:B,N3,D:D,P3)
```

Drag it down and you're done.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I must have been using MINIFs wrong! I utilised UNIQUE & MINIFS to give me this disired outcoime! thank you Isolated!

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, use Power Query (*available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365*). Group by columns A, B & D; and for operation set to the Minimum of Column C

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
            {"A", type text}, {"B", type text}, {"C", type number}, {"D", type text}
            }),


    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"A", "B", "D"}, {
            {"C", each List.Min([C]), type nullable number}
            }),
    
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"A", "B", "C", "D"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

[image]